# Why does the Hartman-Grobman Theorem only apply to Hyperbolic Equilibria?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't understand why we have this restriction. For one problem in my textbook I plotted the phase plane and it looked like a center, as the linearization would predict since the eigenvalues of the Jacobian were plus or minus i.

Is this just a case where the two turned out to match. In general, is it not true that the actual system will look like a center even if the Jacobian has non-hyperbolic eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it was a coincidence.

> Consider for example the equations $$x'=0=0x\quad\text{and}\quad x'=x^3.$$ Notice that in a neighborhood of the origin, $x^3$ is a "small" perturbation of $0$. But the phase portrait of the equation $x'=x^3$ is the same as that of $x'=-x$.